# Changing Menu Path to node/edit

Tags: 6, routes

Is it posible to make a copy of primary menu with changed paths?

For example instead of node/56, I need to rewrite the path to node/56/edit.
The purpose of this is to have the new menu in my Admin Panel, so the site administrator can click on a link to go directly to node edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with the "views" module by using the node edit link available as field. If you don't really need to keep the menu hierarchy, creating view would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've got it. I'm using:

- [Menu Node API](http://drupal.org/project/menu_node) -- to manage relationships between node ids and menu items;
- and [Menu Node Views](http://drupal.org/project/menu_node_views) -- to make View of type 'Menu tree'

I then made a new view with these settings (called primary_link_in_admin):

- **Filter** - Menu: Menu name = primary-links (or whatever you need)
- **Sort criteria** - Menu: Weight asc
- **Fields** -

  - Menu: Link path  - **Exclude from display**
  - Menu: Link title  - **with overridden values** - Output this field as a link → Link path: [link_path]/edit

So I have my Primary Menu in the admin section of the site and a site administrator is able to click on any menu link and goes directly to node/edit on that node. In that way I have very clean Admin section of my Drupal site....(perfect for small - brochure type sites)

That's why I love Drupal and it's community :)
[image: screenshot of new menu view]

Answer (score 1):

Use [menu clone](http://drupal.org/project/menu_clone), then manually change paths for cloned menu.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

It is an option but It's not dinamyc. 
For example if the administrator create new node it doesn't apear in the clone menu.

Now I'am trying to achive this using Menu Node API and Menu Node Views but still without success. 
With Menu Node Views I can have a View type: Menu tree and I've got all my menu links. But sitll I can not change the Link path. I am triyng to overide Link path in my view but when I use "[nid] == Menu: Node id" the whole menu disapear...